# How to return data from subscribe() in RxJava?

Tags: android, rx-java

I need a help. I need to return value from subscribe() in RxJava but I can't understand how to do it. Help my please

```
 private fun getCoordinates() {
    getLastDeviceLocation()
        ?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        ?.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        ?.subscribe({ location ->
           // I need to return location
        },
            { Log.i("ERROR", "error = ${it.localizedMessage}") }
        )
}
```

Comment: where do you want to return the location? where is it supposed to appear

Comment: I need to return the location to ViewModel, in the view module I am doing an api request and the location is one of the api request parameters

Comment: You can assign the location with livedata and Observe the livedata location form activity.

Comment: @Noban Hasan yes, this is exactly what I do in my  ViewModel, but now I work with rxjava  in a simple class which I cannot extend ViewModel() and I need to transfer data from the simple class to my ViewModel class for api request

Answer (score 0):

For your reference, try the below code to return a value using RX java

```
public class Test {
    public static Observable<File> getFile(final String id) {
        return Observable.defer(() => {
          try {
            return Observable.just(getFile(id));
          } catch (WhateverException e) {
            return Observable.error(e);
          }
        });
    }
}


//somewhere in the app
public void doingThings(){
  ...
  // Synchronous
  Test.getFile(5)
   .subscribe(new OnSubscribed<File>(){
     public void onNext(File file){ // your file }
     public void onComplete(){  }
     public void onError(Throwable t){ // error cases }
  });

  // Asynchronous, each observable subscription does the whole operation from scratch
  Test.getFile("5")
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
   .subscribe(new OnSubscribed<File>(){
     public void onNext(File file){ // your file }
     public void onComplete(){  }
     public void onError(Throwable t){ // error cases }
  });

  // Synchronous and Blocking, will run the operation on another thread while the current one is stopped waiting.
  // WARNING, DANGER, NEVER DO IN MAIN/UI THREAD OR YOU MAY FREEZE YOUR APP
  File file = 
  Test.getFile("5")
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
   .toBlocking().first();
  
}
```

Comment: here the Observable returns, but I need to return the value to pass it to the method parameters

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm late, but I was looking for an answer for the same question.
In my project the next approach helped me. I have a MVP architecture and the next code in my presenter:

```
.subscribe{ response -> // response type is User
     view.initProfile(response)
 }
```

And next code in my view:

```
fun initProfile(user: User) {
        input_firstName.setText(user.firstName)
        input_lastName.setText(user.lastName)
        input_patronymic.setText(user.patronymic)
        input_university.setText(user.university)
        input_email.setText(user.email)
        input_phoneNumber.setText(user.phoneNumber)
    }
```

So, by this way I extracted data